# Find out in how many ways the people left the floor.

Tags: combinatorics

Seven people enter a lift. The lift stops at three (unspecified) floors. At each of the three floors, no one enters the lift, but at least one person leaves the lift. After the three floor stops, the lift is empty. In how many ways can this happen.

[image]

Comment: Look up multisets with n=4 and k=3. The reason n=4 is because the first 3 are dedicated to one at each stop, as required.

Comment: @Coolwater, I am not getting. what to do you mean by multisets. May be I am missing any terminology.

Comment: Please edit your question to show any attempt you have made to solve the problem.

Comment: Your attempt is correct if it matters which person does what. I assumed it didnt.

Comment: If the people are indistinguishable then you can use the stars-and-bars method, i.e. number of ways to split seven people into three groups, which is $${6\choose 2}=15$$